# How to do equality comparisons in an if-else block in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm new to Java but I'm lost on the below code. It's not printing out the cost:

```
boolean Smart;
boolean Flat;
int smallsmart = 322;
int largesmart = 405;

void price(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("%nWhat Type of TV would you like Smart of Flat ???  ");//Prompts
    boolean TV = in.next() != null;

    System.out.println("What Size would you like 32 or 42 inch ?? ");//Prompts
    int Size = in.nextInt();    

    if (TV = Smart && Size == 32){//start of if 
        System.out.println("The Price of your Tv is " + smallsmart);    
    } else if (TV = Smart & Size == 42){//start of if 
        System.out.println("The Price of your Tv is " + largesmart);
    }
```

Comment: `in.next() != null` is always true.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: `TV = Smart`is not a comparison but an assignment

Answer (score 0):

Smart will be false (default value of boolean)

In if and else if condition , you mentioned TV = Smart
Which will be false for both the conditions. 
That's why it is no printing anything.

Please correct your code. TV == SMART

Answer (score 0):

You did not assign a value to both of Smart and Flat booleans.

1 equals sign `=` means assign new value.
2 equals signs mean compare the two values,
so `TV = Smart` actually means that you are assigning the value of `Smart` to your `TV` variable.

You should change it to `if (TV == Smart)`

Answer (score 0):

`in.next() != null` is always true.
`Smart` is always false since it has its default value.
So `TV == Smart` is also always false.

You want

```
String TV = in.next();
// ...
if (TV == "Smart" && ...
```

or

```
boolean smart = in.next() == "Smart";
// ...
if (smart && ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean smart;
boolean flat;
int smallSmart = 322;
int largeSmart = 405;

void price(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What Type of TV would you like Smart of Flat ???");
    String typeOfTv = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    if(typeOfTv.equals("smart")) {
        smart = true;
    } else if(typeOfTv.equals("flat")) {
        flat = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("You have not selected an appropritate TV. Exiting...");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("What Size would you like 32 or 42 inch ?? ");//Prompts
    int size = in.nextInt();    

    if (smart && size == 32){//start of if 
        System.out.println("The Price of your Tv is " + smallSmart);    
    } else if (smart & size == 42){//start of if 
        System.out.println("The Price of your Tv is " + largeSmart);
    }
}
```

First of all, I'd recommend you name variables with camel case convention.

Here you are assigning TV to Smart

```
TV = Smart
```

= is used to assign values to variables and == is used to compare.

Answer (score 0):

There is several things that you should have in mind.

First, I advise you to learn about the Java naming convention. Your variables, per example, should be lower-case (`smart` instead of `Smart`). Here it is a link to an Oracle document about that: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

---

Second, there is a big difference between `=` and `==`. The first it's an **assignment**, the second it's a **comparation**.

---

Third, the diference is not that big, but you shoul choose well between using just one `&` or two. In `if` statements its a bit of a deal. With one (`&`), it just means **AND**, with two (`&&`), it also means **AND**, with a tweak: It "short-circuits".

What is "short-circuits"? in resume it is *math* kicking in. In this case:

> 1 AND 'something' = 'something';
>
> 0 AND 'something' = 0 (With `&&` will short-cricuit)

Shurt-circuit is good when in an `if` statment you whant to check if a certain variable is null **BEFORE** using it, to avoid throwing an `NullPointerException`. Like this:

```java
if( variable != null && variable.isSomething() ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

If the variable `variable` is null (therefore `variable != null` is `false`), it will short-circuit to `false`, and it won't throw an exception because it won't attempt to read an non-existing variable.

I advise you to always short-circuit evaluations.

The same thong happens with the **OR** function. You have the plain `|` and the short-circuit one `||`. In this the *math* is:

> 0 OR 'something' = 'something'
>
> 1 OR 'something' = 1 (With `||` will short-cricuit)

---

Forth, be careful when writing things like `boolean TV = in.next() != null;`, in the case on `Scanner` (I'm certain of it) it will not return null, but it might return an empty `String`.

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)